# MVVMCross update error: does not contain a definition for 'EndingWith' and no extension method 'EndingWith'

Tags: c#, cross-platform, mvvmcross

I am working on Windows Universal App using Visual Studio 2013.

I've just upgraded MVVMCross in my solution via nuget and in the App.cs, the following method used to work without problem

```
  public class App : MvxApplication
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        CreatableTypes()
            .EndingWith("Service")
            .AsInterfaces()
            .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

        RegisterAppStart<ViewModels.StartViewModel>();
    }
}
```

However after the upgrade I get the following error

```
Error   2   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Type>' does not contain a definition for 'EndingWith' and no extension method 'EndingWith' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Type>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\Users\Vicky\OneDrive\Dev\WUA\KpopQuiz.Core\KpopQuiz.Core\App.cs  11  18  KpopQuiz.Core
```

Is the `EndingWith` depreciated or is there a new way of Initialing the `Service` classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add a reference with `using MvvmCross.Platform.IoC;` to use it.